# Type Observable<{} | AppUser> is not assignable to <AppUser> RxJS Of operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Using Angular 6.1 and RxJs 6, I'm trying to implement a resolver for a component on an individual user.

My `userService` http call is this:

```
getUserById(id: string): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.http.get<AppUser>(this.baseURL + id, httpOptions);
}
```

And my resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Resolve, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { AppUser } from "../models/User/IAppUser";
import { UserService } from "../services/users/user.service";
import { AlertifyService } from "../../coreModule/alertify/alertify.service";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailResolver implements Resolve<AppUser> {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService
  ) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.userService.getUserById(route.params['id'])
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving data');
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          return of(null)
        })
      );
  }
```

But because I'm trying to return null instead of an `AppUser` typescript is throwing an error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong since I thought rxjs `of` was supposed to handle this.

Comment: try `catchError<any, AppUser>(`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
of(null as AppUser)
```

or

```
of(undefined as AppUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but you have a method that is declared to return a stream of `AppUser`, which implements interface `Resolve<AppUser>`. And with `catchError` + `of(null)` that method is effectively returning a stream of *either `null` or `AppUser`*. As the TS compiler is rightfully complaining about.

**To fix this you may either** return an [`EMPTY` observable](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY). It emits no values and immediately completes. `NEVER` is another constant observable that will never emit and never complete. Pick the one you need. E.g.

```js
catchError(()=>{
  // ...
  return EMPTY;
})
```

*NOTE: with this approach you might need to do type casting, e.g. `EMPTY as Observable<AppUser>`. Though it will be an honest casting — as empty observable can be of any type of observable.*

**Or** if you do need to emit a `null` value on the stream — declare the method as returning `Observable<AppUser | null>`, which is the actual type that it currently returns. And you'll have to also update the `Resolve<AppUser>` to `Resolve<AppUser | null>`.

==

**TO EMPHASIZE THIS:**
In most cases you don't want to lie to your typing system and force cast a `Observable<null | AppUser>` type to a `Observable<AppUser>`.

==

Hope it helps